# How can I create a click event on a google map marker in a cluster?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am working from Google's [Marker Clustering guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering).

I just want to add a simple event to the markers inside a cluster.

Unfotunately, I cannot use `marker.addListener('click', ...` because no `marker` variable is declared.

Any idea how to add a click event to multiple markers using the same markup in the clustering guide?

Many thanks!

Comment: Modify the code to give you access to the marker (it does create one...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrate Google Maps MarkerClusterer with infowindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40047210/integrate-google-maps-markerclusterer-with-infowindow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in [Integrate Google Maps MarkerClusterer with infowindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40047210/integrate-google-maps-markerclusterer-with-infowindow), a marker should be created with a click event:

```
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
    //Add click event
  });
  return marker;
});
```

Here is the solution added to Google's [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) example: https://jsfiddle.net/9dmj3rkr/

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasted 8 hours before reach you. One last problem I am facing, can I hide previous infoWindow when click on another marker?